# Why is this webpage not working?

Tags: javascript, html

In this code, when you click on the submit button, it does not display the alert message. However, it works when you remove the object and property definitions.

```
<--!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>This is just a test</title>
      <script src="script.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
      <h1>This is going to be the search bar</h1>
      <form>
      <input type="text" id="BookName" name="Book1">
      <input type="submit" id="Searchbtn" onclick="algo()">
    </form>
      <script>

      function algo(){
         alert("It is working");
       };
       var search = document.getElementById("BookName");

       var bookDirectory = {};
       bookDirectory.book1 = {
         bookName = "book1",
         bookTag1 = "MAIT",
         bookTag2 = "3rd Semester"
       };

       bookDirectory.book2 = {
         bookName = "book2",
         bookTag1 = "NIEC",
         bookTag2 = "1st Semester"
       };

       bookDirectory.book3 = {
         bookName = "book3",
         bookTag1 = "USIT",
         bookTag2 = "5th Semester"
       };




      </script>
      <h2 id="Book1">This is going to be the book</h2>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Why does it work if you remove the object and property definitions?:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>This is just a test</title>
  <script src="script.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <h1>This is going to be the search bar</h1>
  <form>
  <input type="text" id="BookName" name="Book1">
  <input type="submit" id="Searchbtn" onclick="algo()">
</form>
  <script>

  function algo(){
     alert("It is working");
   };



  </script>
  <h2 id="Book1">This is going to be the book</h2>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "However, it works only when you remove the objects and defined search variable" By objects, you are referring to?

Comment: You should take more careful look at how to write an object literal. Now their "definitions" are breaking your code, and `algo` will never be defined,

Comment: Have you tried using firebug to see if there are any errors in your code?

Comment: To many errors, Starting from `bookName = "book2"` BTW this question is off topic.

Comment: I think the question was clear enough; just because it's regarding a common syntax doesn't mean that the question is immediately "wrong" when the poster isn't familiar with it.

Answer (score 3):

You are incorrectly defining your [Object Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Object_literals).

Instead of using the `=` in your definitions:

```
bookDirectory.book1 = {
     bookName = "book1",
     bookTag1 = "MAIT",
     bookTag2 = "3rd Semester"
};
```

You *should* be defining them with `:`, like so:

```
bookDirectory.book1 = {
     bookName: "book1",
     bookTag1: "MAIT",
     bookTag2: "3rd Semester"
   };
```

Because these are defined using an incorrect syntax, the entire `<script>` block and all the code within it is invalid and not available for use.

Please note that most browsers you might use for testing have a development console which you can use to check for errors, and this incorrect assignment would definitely have shown in your console.  For most browsers, the default key to open the developer panel is <kbd>F12</kbd>.